# InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

Just upgraded a web project to .NET 6.0. Project compiles but when I run the site I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location
> for package 'System.Security.Cryptography'.

I am using MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc 4.2.2.
For debugging, I added NuGet System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs package but that does not fix the problem.

Any troubleshooting ideas?

The stack shows that **MiniProfilerMiddleware.cs** is throwing the exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs'
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPartExtensions+<>c.<GetReferencePaths>b__0_0(CompilationLibrary library)
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetReferencePaths()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(string normalizedPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilder+<>c+<<BuildPipeline>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.ResponseCachingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in MiniProfilerMiddleware.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: I guess this is  MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc use the old dll and it throw this issue, I suggest you could ask this issue at this github [issue](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues).

Comment: It actually nothing to do with MiniProfiler - it was a missing DLL (see answer). MiniProfiler was just the last component in the Exception details but not the offending one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**The fix:**
Add the following configuration setting to your .csproj file.

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
```

It seems that this issue is most likely [related to a breaking change with .NET 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16818) which was not documented. It worked for me, without adding/removing any of the above mentioned libraries.

Comment: Worked like a charm!
More specifically, open the project.csproj file in a texteditor and add the above line into the <PropertyGroup> </PropertyGroup> configuration.
Thanks for the hint!!

Answer (score 5):

It turns out it had nothing to do with MiniProfiler. Instead, @NickCraver suggested that https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs/ was not copied to the `bin` folder. After copying the DLL manually, project runs again.

Next challenge, is that I am not using the DLL directly in the code, so perhaps it is some older NuGet that is referencing it.

https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/587

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with a project I'm working on, but ***only*** when trying to run it in IIS. It would work fine running as a standalone EXE (using Kestrel) but not when hosted in IIS. I had tried all of the other solutions and nothing made a difference.

What finally worked for me was **changing the Identity for the project's IIS App Pool to my own user account**. It was running as "ApplicationPoolIdentity" before, and my local NuGet cache directory was not being included in the list of resolution paths. Changing the identity to my own user fixed it.

Comment: Based on your comment, I did something similar.  Instead of setting the App Pool to use my name, I allowed the App Pool to view the Nuget Packages folder.  Works too.